# cp command saying directory does not exist when it does

Tags: bash, shell-script, file-copy

I'm writing a bash script and in it I'm doing something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p "Enter target directory: " target_dir
cp some/file.txt $target_dir/exists/for/sure/
```

When I run this shell script I see and input:

```
./my_script.sh
Enter target directory: ~/my_dir
```

But I get the error/output:

```
cp: directory ~/my_dir/exists/for/sure/ does not exist
```

And, as I'm trying to make obvious: That directory 100% exists. i.e. I can run the following without receiving any error:

```
cd ~/my_dir/exists/for/sure/
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, that `~` is taken literally and not expanded when you type it as input for `read`.

Test it:

```
$ read target
~
$ ls $target
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

(note, the quotes around `~`)

---

[Use this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)

```
eval target=$target # unsafe
```

or better, but expands just `~`:

```
target="${target/#\~/$HOME}"
```

or even better, do not type variables or alike into `read` in the first place.